# Why do I get a No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of show error?

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck on this problem and I'm very new to Haskell, I was trying to complete the first Euler problem with the following code:

```
main = putStrLn . show . sum $ [3,6..1000]:[5,10..1000]
```

And here's the first part of the error:

```
euler/1.hs:1:19:
    No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of `show'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 23 others
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `show'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `show . sum'
    In the expression: putStrLn . show . sum
```

Comment: The `Show` error is a red herring here caused by the fact that integer literals are overloaded in Haskell. Try with `[3::Int,6..1000]:[5::Int,10..1000]` to get a better error message.

Comment: Instead of `[...]:[...]` I think you want `[...] ++ [...]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you expect `[3,6..1000]:[5,10..1000]` to do? `x : xs` preppeds an object to a list of objects. Here both arguments are lists of integers. Did you want `++` instead (concatenation).

It needs to be said that your approach is not right, no matter what you expected `:` to do. I'll not expand on this in case you want to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the error message you get is missing the problem. Loading it in ghci 7.4.2 gives much more helpful error messages:

```
No instance for (Num [t0])
  arising from a use of `sum'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t0])
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `sum'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `show . sum'
In the expression: putStrLn . show . sum

No instance for (Enum [t0])
  arising from the arithmetic sequence `5, 10 .. 1000'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Enum [t0])
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `[5, 10 .. 1000]'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `[3, 6 .. 1000] : [5, 10 .. 1000]'
In the expression:
  putStrLn . show . sum $ [3, 6 .. 1000] : [5, 10 .. 1000]
```

This seems to hint that the problem is in the expression `[3, 6 .. 1000] : [5, 10 .. 1000]` and indeed it is because the type of `:` is  `a -> [a] -> [a]` and `x:xs` simply adds the element `x` to the beginning of the list `xs`. In `[3, 6 .. 1000] : [5, 10 .. 1000]`
you are trying to add `[3, 6 .. 1000]` as an element to `[5, 10 .. 1000]`, but lists in haskell must contain elements of the same type (they are homogeneous) so that will not work. This is because `[3, 6 .. 1000]` has the type `[Int]` and the elements of `[5, 10 .. 1000]` has the type `Int`.

I think that what you are looking for is `++` which has the type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` and `xs ++ ys` is the concatenation of the list `xs` and the list `ys`:

```
ghci> putStrLn . show . sum $ [3,6..1000] ++ [5,10..1000]
267333
```